# Material ui v5 Core components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am upgrading mui from v4 to v5

Here we have https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#core-components

> As the core components use emotion as their style engine, the props used by emotion are not intercepted. The prop as in the following code snippet will not be propagated to SomeOtherComponent.

```js
<MuiComponent component={SomeOtherComponent} as="button" />
```

So what must I do If I want to pass `as` to `SomeOtherComponent` as props?

And where is the list of **the props used by emotion**